# SQL Server. Using Variables in Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird problem in SQL Server I try to insert a value of @a in TableB but it is always NULL. I check the @a value by adding Print line.. it has a value.
and I try to replace it with a fixed integer. it works.
why and how to solve that?

```
declare @a integer
set @a = select top 1 field1 from tableA
print @a
insert into tableB (f1,f2,f2, @a)
    FROM
    Select f1, f2, f3 from TableC
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable for the name of a column.  Do you mean something like this?

```
insert into tableB (f1, f2, f3, f4)
    Select f1, f2, f3, @a
    from TableC;
```

You have multiple errors in your code sample.  You can't list a column twice in the column list for `insert`.  There is a `FROM` that is just hanging out there.  And the `set` is incorrect.  It should be:

```
set @a = (select top 1 field1 from tableA)
```

Comment: @SamerASSIL . . . You are getting `NULL`s because `tableA.field1` is sometimes `NULL` or there are no rows in the table.